# How to align the page number on the right in a footer with Latex and the scrbook package?

Tags: latex, alignment

I am writing a Latex document using the scrbook package.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{scrbook}
\pagestyle{plain}
```

The page number always appears centered in the footer. How can I make it align on the right?
I've tried several times to find it in the documentation but to be honest, I don't fully understand it and my deadline is now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\ifoot[]{}
\cfoot[]{}
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}

\pagestyle{scrplain}
```

should do it.

Comment: Thank you, you're positively awesome!